# addAttributeToFilter with mutiselect values

Tags: magento-1.9, collection-filtering

I have to apply filter on base of field "status", which is multi select.i.e if I have to filter for following values "Closed,Completed,On Hold",I tied following

```
$orderCollection    = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();



 $orderCollection->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('in' => array('Closed','Completed','On Hold')));
```

This is not working,

Comment: 'Closed', 'Completed' and 'On Hold' are not the actual field values, but the (translatable) labels. Try 'closed', 'complete' and 'holded'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array('closed','complete','holded')));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use collection field filter:

```
$orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array('closed','completed','holded')));
```